# Solution for 1 GCP network-to-many GCP networks VPN topologies that addresses internal IP ambiguity

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem where our firm has many GCP projects, and I need to expose services on my project to these distinct GCP projects. Firewalling in individual IPs isn't really sustainable, as we dynamically spin up and tear down hundreds of GCE VMs a day.

I've successfully joined a network from my project to another project via GCP's VPN, but I'm not sure what the best practice should be joining multiple networks to my single network, especially since most of the firm has the same default internal address subnetwork range for the project's default network. I understand that doing it the way that I am will probably work ([it's unclear if it'll actually reach the right network, though](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#tunnels_with_overlapping_ip_ranges)), but this creates a huge ambiguity in terms of IP collisions, where potentially two VMs could exists in separate networks and have the same internal IP.

I've read that outside of the cloud, most VPNs support [NAT remapping](http://www.nimlabs.org/dirtynat.html), which seems to let you remap the internal IP space of the remote peer's subnet (like, 10.240.* to 11.240.*), such that you can never have ambiguity from the peer doing the remapping.

I also know that [Cloud Router](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cloudrouter) may be an option, but it seems like a solution to a very specific problem that doesn't fully encompass this one: dynamically adding and removing subnets to the VPN.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to call off-topic. This isn't really a programming problem, this is more networking. Try serverfault, maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a general networking problem rather than a GCP one since I mentioned this can be done with a NAT remap in non-GCP, but I was also unsure where to post. I posted here because most questions related to GCP VPN and Cloud Router were asked on SO with the google-cloud-platform tag...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to utilize the custom subnet mode network (non-default), specify non-overlapping IP ranges for the networks to avoid collision. See "Creating a new network with custom subnet ranges" in this doc: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks#networks_and_subnetworks

Comment: It's kind of a unring-that-bell situation...all the projects across my firm are pretty much "auto" subnets already, which will default to something like 10.240.X.X. We can't really make everyone change their subnets.